# Why is the relationship between molar mass and boiling point for alkanes a square root relationship?

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, boiling-point

I plotted the boiling point of alkanes against their molar mass and found the following trend: [image: Graph showing boiling point trend]

I expected the trend would be linear, since (based on my understanding of what I've learned in class so far) for non polar molecules like alkanes, the boiling point depends on London dipole forces acting between them, and these are proportional to surface area. As such, I expected that as CH$_2$ were added, the surface area of consecutive alkanes would increase linearly with their mass and thus the London forces and boiling point would also increase linearly with mass.

However, as can be seen in the graph above, the relationship between boiling point and mass seems to roughly follow a square root trend.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Just for fun, when you plot boiling point vs. number of carbon atoms what do you get? Hopefully a straight line. These mathematical musings currently do not have a solid base, however such relationships are good for predictions. However square root relationship is not universal. Boiling point or melting point is among the hardest things to predict.

Comment: Also read about "Correlation does not imply causation" on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

Comment: Also consider this: surface *area* does not grow *linearly* with extra carbons. Try calculating the actual surface area and plotting that against BP.

Comment: Is the units of your molar mass g/mol? If so, where did you get data for boiling points of such large alkanes? In the range of hundreds to thousands g/mol, polymer phenomena starts to become relevant and one might expect very different behavior than for the lighter alkanes. For instance, polyethylene (alkane with MM > 1000 g/mol) will never boil, and instead degrades around 650 K. Similar effects might be relevant at the scale you're considering here, unless you've been able to rule that out.

Comment: @matt_black, can you please provide a reference for your statement? According to data from [Zhao et al. (2003)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo034808o), the van der Waals surface area does [grow _linearly_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEvzA.png) for linear alkanes  (at least up to $n=10$).